# position:fixed navigation stop at end of specific div - parallax scrolling & javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, css-position, parallax

I have a vertically oriented vertical navigation bar, that I would like to make stop at the end of `#contact`. It will need to resume scrolling again if the user scrolls back up. 
What is the best way to achieve this?

javascript being used:

```
$(function() {
            $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
                return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
            };

            var $el = $('#nav>div');
            var $window = $(window);
            var top = $el.parent().position().top;

            $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
                var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 10;
                var visibleFoot = 340 - $window.scrollBottom();
                var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

                if (scrollTop < top + 10) {
                    $el.css({
                        top: (top - scrollTop) + "px",
                        bottom: "auto"
                    });
                } else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
                    $el.css({
                        top: "auto",
                        bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
                    });
                } else {
                    $el.css({
                        top: 0,
                        bottom: "auto"
                    });
                }
            }).scroll();
        });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVmeD/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the code you are looking for:

```
$(function() {
    var $Nav = $('#Nav');
    var $window = $(window);
    var $contact = $('#contact');
    var maxTop = $contact.offset().top + $contact.height() - $Nav.height();
    window.navFixed = 1;

    $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
        var currentTop = $window.scrollTop();
        if (currentTop <= maxTop && window.navFixed == 0) {
            $Nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '5%'
            });
            window.navFixed = 1;
        } else if (currentTop > maxTop && window.navFixed == 1) {
            $Nav.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: maxTop
            });
            window.navFixed = 0;
        }
    }).scroll();
});
```

The `#Nav` element contains the CSS you had originally specified: `position: fixed; top: (...)`. When the document is ready, the variable `maxTop` is calculated based on the `#contact` element's top and height.

On the `scroll` and `resize` event, the variable `currentTop` is calculated as the current scroll position. If this value is lower than `maxTop`, then `#Nav` is set to the original CSS; if the value is higher, new CSS styles are applied: `position: absolute; top: maxTop;`

`window.navFixed` is used to prevent the CSS to be constantly updated while scrolling. I'm sure that bit can be improved, however, it demonstrates its purpose.

Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVmeD/2/) for the full HTML..

PS. *There's a minor bug in your code, where `#Nav` refers to the `<ul>` element, rather than the `<nav>` element. However, the moving element is the `<ul>`, when it should be `<nav>`.*