# CSS-only scrolling div that stops at other div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

Thanks to javascript contributions from [James Montagne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988697/jquery-scrolling-div-stop-scrolling-when-div-reaches-footer/8989595#8989595) and [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123262/positionfixed-navigation-stop-at-end-of-specific-div-parallax-scrolling-jav), I have code that allows a div to scroll to the end of another div, stop, and resume scrolling if the user scrolls back up.

However, because I have many other divs set to "fixed" or "relative" surrounding these, I'm hoping I can achieve the same scrolling/stopping functionality without javascript (or at least without convoluting the current javascript).

**UPDATE:**
I've finally been able to get closer to my desired output while removing "relatively" positioned elements. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gregpearl/ws4peb5s/8/).

Looks like I'm stuck using javascript for now.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var s = $("#sticker");
    var x = $("#stickShell");

    var pos = s.position();
    var pox = x.position();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        s.html("Distance from top:" + pos.top + "<br />Scroll position: " + windowpos);
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("scroll");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("scroll");
        }
        if (windowpos >= pox.top - 95) {
            s.removeClass("scroll");
            s.addClass("stick");
            s.css({
                'top': pox.top - 95
            });
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick");
            s.css({
                'top': '0px'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainContent">
            <h1>Intro</h1>

        <p>Here's some content. Below, there's a div with an ID of &quot;sticker&quot;. This div starts fixed and will stick there until the viewport reaches its parent div (I've added ugly red borders to show where everything starts and ends).</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="scrollShell">
        <p>The scolling div should load as fixed just below this text and begin scrolling down.</p>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="sticker">...start scrolling to watch me stick</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="extraContent">
            <h1>More Content</h1>

        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="stickShell">
        <p>The scolling div should stick just below this text.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="moreContent">
            <h1>Even More Content</h1>

        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mainContent {
    width:560px;
    padding:20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#extraContent {
    width:560px;
    padding:20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#scrollShell {
    width:560px;
    height:200px;
    padding:20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#stickShell {
    width:560px;
    height:200px;
    padding:20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#moreContent {
    width:560px;
    padding:20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#container {
    width:230px;
    margin-top:-160px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#sticker {
    padding:20px;
    margin:160px 0px 180px 0px;
    background:#AAA;
    width:190px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
.scroll {
    position:fixed;
}
.stick {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done without JS. What might come closest is using `position: sticky` but that has very limited browser support.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Shikkediel. Perhaps if I include a more complete-but-non-working example of what I'm after, it will help: http://jsfiddle.net/gregpearl/Ldmm0m4y/ In this case, I'd like the #scroller div to start in a fixed position toward the bottom of the page. Then, once a user scrolls to a certain level, #scroller would scroll only as far as a specific point, stop, and resume scrolling if the user scrolls back up—again, only to a fixed point, though.

Comment: Rewrote it a bit and removed `position: relative` from `#example` at least. http://tinyurl.com/pha9fys

Comment: Thanks for your time and attention, Shikkediel! Everything looks workable...only #scroller would ideally appear in a fixed position directly under #skeleton on page load. Then, the scrolling effect would (a) begin when #scroller enters the viewing window and (b) end scrolling where it does now. In any case, I think this gets me closer!